# Passing JSON Data to REST POST method

Tags: c#, json, rest, post

I am trying to pass JSON data (present in file) to JSON POST method.

But getting HTTP 400 error (Bad Request) - "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."

Please help.

**Interface -:**

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "/JSON", Method = "POST")]
string CreatePersonFromJSONString(Person createPerson);
```

**Implemented Function -:**

```
 public string CreatePersonFromJSONString(Person createPerson)
  {
     createPerson.ID = (++personCount).ToString();
     persons.Add(createPerson);
     return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(createPerson);
  }
```

**Program -:**

```
 HttpWebRequest req = WebRequest.Create(uri) as HttpWebRequest;
 req.KeepAlive = false;
 req.Method = Method.ToUpper();

if (("POST,PUT").Split(',').Contains(Method.ToUpper()))
 {
   Console.WriteLine("Enter JSON FilePath:");
   string FilePath = Console.ReadLine();
   content = (File.OpenText(@FilePath)).ReadToEnd();

    req.ContentType = "application/json;";

    //initiate the request
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var resToWrite = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(content);
    StreamWriter PostData = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    PostData.Write(resToWrite);
    PostData.Flush();
    PostData.Close();
}

  HttpWebResponse resp = req.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

**Input File Content -:**

```
{  "Age":"25",
       "ID":"4",
       "Name":"Ashish" 
    }
```

**Person Class -:**

```
 [DataContract]
    public class Person
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string ID;
        [DataMember]
        public string Name;
        [DataMember]
        public string Age;
    }
```

> Uri - http://localhost:5171/RestService/JSON
>
> Method - POST

Comment: Can you hit your REST service via a rest client such as Post Man? I tried your JSON doesn't seem to be valid. Go to http://jsonlint.com/ and paste your JSON in. Humor me, and use this as your input 
{
 "Age": "25",
 "ID": "4",
 "Name": "Ashish"
}

Comment: I am able to test this using Advanced Rest Client by passing the JSON text. I have also corrected the input JSON. But still getting the same error. Most probably the error is in passing of JSON data in request stream.

 req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    //initiate the request
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var resToWrite = serializer.Deserialize<Person>(content);
    StreamWriter PostData = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream());
    PostData.Write(resToWrite);
    PostData.Flush();
    PostData.Close();

Comment: When you hit it via a rest client do you get a bad request still?

Comment: No. I getting the desired output when hitting from Rest Client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to me your JSON is invalid.

In JSON the property names must be in quotes so:

```
{
   "Age":"25",
   "ID":"4",
   "Name":"Ashish" 
}
```

Comment: I have corrected the JSON data. But still getting the same error

Answer (score 1):

I had to change the writing of data to Request Stream.
No need to deserialize the JSON.

Changed program part -:

```
byte[] buffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
req.ContentLength = buffer.Length;
Stream PostData = req.GetRequestStream();
PostData.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
PostData.Close();
```

Comment: Rather than having the word "SOLVED" in your answer, you "accept" it. Have a look at this answer on meta: [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)